# How can I address several deans in a letter?

Tags: etiquette

I am part of the student council at my college and I would like to email a letter to all of the deans.

How can I start the letter without writing "Dear Deans?"

Comment: I never use "Dear" when formally addressing anyone. When addressing professors or more generally people higher up the food chain, I address them with an honorific if applicable followed by their last name. So in this case, I'd say "Deans ABC, DEF, etc."

Comment: As we can see below, this probably depends on local custom and culture, so you should say where you are.  I'd do whatever would be considered appropriate for a formal business letter in your culture.  I don't think it's likely to be specific to academia.

Comment: What's wrong with "Dear Deans"?

Answer (score 3):

One solution would be: instead of sending a single email addressed to all of them, send each one a separate message, addressed to them personally and with an appropriate salutation.  This is also more likely to get their attention than something that appears to be a mass-mailed form letter.  If it's important that they know the same letter is being sent to the other deans, say so in the text.

Comment: I'll prefer this option then.

Answer (score 1):

It might not be pleasing to most people of higher ranks to address with "Dear" at the start of a contact, especially if it is from a student. I suppose a better option would be to include this.

> Respected Dignitaries

This should be the most pleasing way to address rank officials such as deans, professors, and chief guests.

Comment: This is likely to vary by culture.  In contrast to this, in a US business or academic environment, "Dear" is perfectly acceptable for all formal letters, regardless of the "rank" of the sender or recipient, and "Respected Dignitaries" would sound hilariously pompous, or even mocking.

Comment: If that's so, Dear Dignitaries, may be a better fit for that culture.

Comment: I think "Dignitaries" itself is way over the top for US.  It suggests princes, ambassadors, heads of state with fancy clothes, and sounds odd applied to a mere academic dean.

Comment: It seems like it is a bit overused from where I came from. So its seems appropriate. (PS: Today's heads of states do not wear fancy clothes.)

Comment: I know they don't - that is my point!

Comment: Nonetheless, in literature, dignitaries do refer to important persons as well. The word has not archaic meaning as of now, hence it is applicable under the sense stated in the question.